# How to list only files not folder in GCS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to GCS. I'm trying to list the files in a "folder" & download them, however my list is return the folder name as index 0.

How do I only list the files name and not the name of the directory?  Or should I just shift() the array after I get the list back?

```
const prefix = 'testFiles/'; //contains jpgs
const delimiter = '/';
    const options = {
        prefix: prefix,
      };

      if (delimiter) {
        options.delimiter = delimiter;
      }

const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

files.forEach((file, i) => {
    options.destination = `./downloads/${i}.jpg`
    console.log(options);
    file.download(options)
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Storage does not have real "folders". Instead, they are emulated using the prefix and delimiter parameters to the [List Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) method.

The way you're doing it is correct. But when you list with a prefix, all objects that start with that prefix are returned, up to the delmiter, if specified. That means, like you found, that if have a "directory placeholder" object (an object that ends in `/`), it will be returned. Note that it also means any "subdirectories" of that prefix will also be returned. For example, if you have the following list of objects in a bucket:

```
testFiles/
testFiles/a
testFiles/b
testFiles/c/d
testFiles/v
```

If you call list objects with `prefix=testFiles/` and `delimiter=/`, you'll have the following returned:

```
items =
  testFiles/
  testFiles/a
  testFiles/b
  testFiles/v
prefixes =
  testFiles/c/
```

This is because `testFiles/` is actually an object in your bucket in GCS.

Comment: So how would I only get: testFiles/a, 
    testFiles/b, 
    testFiles/v

Comment: You can't, that's not the way the API works. In your case, there **is** an object named `testFiles/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `matchGlob` parameter, with something like: `**[^/]`, to list only files that don't end with `/` (folders).

In your case, it should be:

```js
[...]
const prefix = 'testFiles/'; //contains jpgs
const matchGlob = '**[^/]'; // or simply '**.jpg'
const options = {
   prefix,
   matchGlob
};

const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
[...]
```

For reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list#list-objects-and-prefixes-using-glob